# Same disk: Installing Linux - a lottery. Win - flawless

Tags: linux, arch-linux, system-installation, elementary-os, solus

I have tried dual boot as well as Linux on the entire disk - same problem. When the nvme is mounted and when trying to write to it; sooner or later it freezes and journalctl says that it can not write to it. Then it is lost, does not show up w/ lsblk.

Tried with arch, solus and elementary, a couple of times it has worked but 99.6% of the times it is a fail.

Has been posted on the arch forum for some time now without success. Details [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=253517)

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware. Many with various issues have found that fixes them. This may not apply but is another reason to update. UEFI update required for USB-C port issues 2017 thru 2019 models
ThinkPad models including the ThinkPad X1 Carbon (5th Gen to 7th Gen), X1 Yoga (2nd Gen to 4th Gen), and P-series 
https://www.cnet.com/news/is-your-thinkpads-usb-c-port-not-working-upgrade-its-firmware/

Answer (score 0):

I hear ya having a little trouble. I have a dell with a NVME and can dual boot. What I had to do (which might work). I did a Linux live boot with Mint 19.x and opened up a terminal. Then did a zero wipe using shred like so,
sudo shred -n 1 -v -z /dev/sdx . The sdx could be sda, sdb or sdc etc.. 
You can make sure it at least do %50 of the NVME (the speed varies). Once that's done boot win10 then select manually half of the partition then install. After that boot Linux and have it install on the free available partition. it should automatically set up the dual boot for you. It worked for me. Try it out.